# onTapUp isn't called after onLongPress

Tags: uigesturerecognizer, flutter, long-press

I'm trying to create a context menu that is displayed after a long press whilst keeping your finger held on the object, afterwards you would select an option (by dragging your finger) and lift it to initiate the action.

I noticed something that to me is a little strange. So first, the code:

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    void main() {
      runApp(MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          body: GestureDetector(
            onLongPress: () {
              print("onLongPress");
            },
            onTapUp: (TapUpDetails details) {
              print("onTapUp");
            },
            child: Center(
              child: FlutterLogo(),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ));
    }
```

So if I run this, after long pressing the icon, then the handler for `onLongPress` is called but after lifting your finger `onTapUp` isn't called. If I comment out the handler for `onLongPress` (all 3 lines) then after a long press `onTapUp` is called. I would like to handle both `onTapUp` and `onLongPress`.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap in another gesture detector that will handle tap up.

I am not sure if current behavior is a bug, so you might want to submit it to issue tracker.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but apparently it still doesn't work. Call it intuition, but I think it might have something to do with how _GestureArenaManager_ works. I've also enable _debugPrintGestureArenaDiagnostics_ but it didn't help much.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the PR will be pass but I've solved it with a new gesture onLongPressUp.

Here is it https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/18949

Comment: Awesome ! I was just looking into this again, I'll check the PR and close the issue (https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17850) if all goes well. Thank you :)